# XmlPullparser parsing xml from url not working

Tags: java, android, xml, inputstream, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to populate a database from an xml file. It work pretty well, but the problem is when I try to load the xml from a server.
I've spent hours and hours, trying lots of different implementations but I always receive an exception.
Here is my current code:

```
public void populateDB(){
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    ArrayList<Product> products = null;

    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream in_s = fContext.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("products.xml");

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in_s, null);

        products =  parseXML(parser);

        String text = "";

        for(Product product:products)
        {

            text += "barcode : " + product.getBarcode() + " name : " + product.getName() + "\n";
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    clearTable("products");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++){
        values.clear();
        values.put("barcode", products.get(i).getBarcode());
        values.put("name", products.get(i).getName());
        values.put("itemcode", products.get(i).getItemcode());
        values.put("description", products.get(i).getDescription());

        insertProduct(values);
    }
}
```

And this is parseXML(), where I parse the file and generate a list of products.

```
private ArrayList<Product> parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
{
    ArrayList<Product> products = null;
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Product product = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        String name;
        switch (eventType){
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                products = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("product")){
                    product = new Product();
                } else if (product != null){
                    if (name.equals("barcode")){
                        product.setBarcode(parser.nextText());
                    } else if (name.equals("name")){
                        product.setName(parser.nextText());
                    } else if (name.equals("itemcode")){
                        product.setItemcode(Integer.parseInt(parser.nextText()));
                    } else if (name.equals("description")){
                        product.setDescription(parser.nextText());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("product") && product != null){
                    products.add(product);
                }
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    return products;

}
```

Now this works only with local files, but if I want to load it from a url?
I tried the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178321/how-to-get-xml-file-from-url-instead-of-getassets) thread, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862962/parsing-xml-from-web), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459146/android-use-xmlpullparser-parse-xml-from-url),
 [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932369/inputstream-from-a-url), but still it doesn't work.

It seems that the instruction `parser.setInput(in_s, null);` does not accept an inputstream containing an url.

The xml file path is the following: http://cendav.altervista.org/gestione_magazzino/products.xml

Comment: So the underlying question is how to get an ``InputStream`` from a url?

Comment: Not properly, because I tried different ways to get the InputStream, reading lots of topics and it never worked. So I don't know if the problem is the InputStream, or the url, or something else.

Comment: your question is how to parse xml?

Comment: No I able to parse the xml but I cannot load it from url.

Comment: what? you can parse the xml but cannot load the url???

Comment: @Orvenito yes, the code I posted above shows when I load it from a local folder, and the rest of the code works great, but the problem is when i try to get this file from the url.

Comment: @pskink yes it is, the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'll put in an asyncTask:

```
class getXMLResponseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
         //do something
        }


        @Override
        public Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(connection.getInputStream());


                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("products");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                    NodeList barcode = element.getElementsByTagName("barcode");
                    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
                    NodeList itemcode = element.getElementsByTagName("itemcode");



                    Element barcodeval = (Element) barcode.item(0);
                    Element nameval = (Element) name.item(0);
                    Element itemcodeval = (Element) itemcode.item(0);



                    String BARCODE = barcodeval.getTextContent();
                    String NAME  = nameval.getTextContent();
                    String ITEMCODE = itemcodeval.getTextContent();


                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        //do something
        }
    }
```

**AND FINALLY YOU CAN USE IT ANYTIME YOU WANT**

```
    new getXMLResponseAsyncTask().execute("http://cendav.altervista.org/gestione_magazzino/products.xml");
```

Comment: This line `DocumentsContract.Document doc = builder.parse((connection.getInputStream()));` gives me the error of incopatible types.

Comment: did you import `import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;` ?

Comment: DocumentsContract.Document doc = builder.parse((connection.getInputStream()));

Incopatible types:
Required: android.provider.DocumentsConrtact.Document
Found: org.w3c.dom.Document

Comment: import these: `import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;`

Comment: and make sure this line `Document doc = builder.parse(connection.getInputStream());`   is is using it.

Comment: and remove this import `android.provider.DocumentsConrtact.Document`